# Magento 2 custom module Collection join table _initSelect

Tags: module, collection, magento2.2.3

My `Collection.php`

```
 .... 
public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
                \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
                \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
            ) {
                $this->_init(
                    'Module\Vendor\Model\Test',
                    'Module\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Test'
                );
                parent::__construct(
                    $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,
                    $resource
                );
                $this->logger = $logger;
                $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
                $this->store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
                $this->storeId = $this->store->getId();
                print_r($this->storeId);//THIS PRINTS ON THE PAGE CORRECT STORE ID
            }

            protected function _initSelect()
            {

                parent::_initSelect();
                $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('my_custom')], //2nd table name by which you want to join
                    'main_table.my_id = secondTable.my_id AND secondTable.store = '.(int)$this->storeId, // HERE DOES NOT WORK! common column which available in both table
                    '*' // '*' define that you want all column of 2nd table. if you want some particular column then you can define as ['column1','column2']
                );

            }
         ....
```

I printing The correct store ID Which is `1` in constructor but in `_initSelect`  Does not seem to work/Available if hard coded `secondTable.store =1'` Then it works.

I don't understand Why Anyone know What could be the reason?

Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the $storeId directly on function without the declaration on __contruct

```
    protected function _initSelect()
        {

            parent::_initSelect();
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('my_custom')], //2nd table name by which you want to join
                'main_table.my_id = secondTable.my_id AND secondTable.store = {$storeId}', // HERE DOES NOT WORK! common column which available in both table
                '*' // '*' define that you want all column of 2nd table. if you want some particular column then you can define as ['column1','column2']
            );

        }
```